# Why can't eclipse enable JDT Weaving?

Tags: eclipse, maven, aspectj, spring-roo, compile-time-weaving

I have created a simple Spring Roo Project in Eclipse Indigo, where the jpa entities where generated using the `dbre` command. When I want to add methods to some class, I'm not able to use the methods the are woven into the entities via the Spring Roo generated aspects.

When I clean and build the project in eclipse, the progress view shows that the aspects are woven into the classes. The build runs fine on the command line with Maven 3.0.4. Maven will also compile code that is marked with compile errors in Eclipse, when methods from the aspects are used.

I tried to enable JDT Weaving via the preferences and also followed the instructions [for manual activation from the eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_weaving_features#Turning_on_JDT_Weaving_manually)

Am I right that the problem I am facing is related to the disabled JDT Weaving feature? If yes, how can I enable JDT Weaving or find the reason why it won't be enabled?

Thanks for help

**EDIT:**
I created a new workspace and imported the Spring Roo project as a Maven project. I see dialog coming up, that wants to convert a legacy STS project. When I confirm, it seems that nothing happens. But now at least I can see Advice Markers in the Entities generated by Spring Roo. However I' still not able to use any method, that was woven in the class.

**EDIT:**
Running JUnit Tests is also no problem, even if there are the compile errors. I'm using Eclipse Indigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled a clean Eclipse Indigo and installed m2e, AJDT and the AJDT configurator for m2eclipse.

After setting up a new workspace and importing the project all worked well.

Note that I've not installed Spring STS.

This is probably a problem between different eclipse plugins.

**EDIT:**
The Spring STS is really the cause of the problem. After installing it, the problem appeared again.